# Tmec 50QT-2 scooter wont start

Tags: starting, troubleshooting, scooter

I have a Tmech 50QT-2 scooter (Chinese type). The scooter revs when using the electronic start button and or the kick start but it will not actually start. just bought a new battery for it and the problem is still there. I am by no means a mechanic but I don't have the money to take it to a shop. If anyone has any ideas please let me know thank you.

P.S it has gas and I bought it brand new in 2013
Also a few times it did turn over but then a few seconds later it dies.

What could the problem be?

Comment: What could the problem be? Chinese low cost manufacturing.

Comment: did the scooter sit for an extended period of time (couple of months or longer) before this issue?

Comment: As long as the engine still has compression, I would say there is a 90% chance the issue is the carburetor. Can you try some starting fluid or spray some gas in the carb?  Can you verify the choke is working?

Comment: Figured it out I guess after letting it sit for a while water must have got into the fuel tank... I cleaned the tank of the old fuel and put in New fuel so now it starts and runs as long as I rev it but when I let go of the throttle it dies down and shuts off... It won't stay running by itself. Is it because it Sat so long?

Comment: If you are user17180 please click the contact us at the bottom of the page and ask to combine your accounts. Then you will be able to edit your original question and add additional detail